# How to make XML Schema work with Namespaces

Tags: xml, namespaces, schema

I'm working on an XML assignment and having a difficult time figuring it out.

Basically I'm creating my first Schema, and I can't figure out how to link the individual namespaces as names. Right now I have:

```
<xs:element name="dist:name" type="xs:string" />
```

Unfortunately that gives an error that the name is not valid NCName. If I remove the namespace it works fine, but conflicts with other things in my XML document then.

I've searched for hours and can't find the solution for this. Here is my code for my XML and for my XSD if it helps.

XML:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="first.xsl"?>
<compPress
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:schema"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schema first.xsd">

<dist:distributor xmlns:dist="http://comppress.com/distributors">
    <dist:name>MetED</dist:name>
    <dist:id>365782</dist:id>
    <dist:description></dist:description>
    <dist:contractDate></dist:contractDate>
    <dist:address></dist:address>
    <dist:contactName>Mark</dist:contactName>
    <dist:serviceRegion>Northeast</dist:serviceRegion>
</dist:distributor>

<div:division xmlns:div="http://comppress.com/divisions">
    <div:name>Penguin</div:name>
    <div:number>9</div:number>
    <div:description></div:description>
    <div:numberEmployees>76</div:numberEmployees>
    <div:creationDate>Feb 1, 2014</div:creationDate>
    <div:mission></div:mission>
</div:division>

<pub:publication xmlns:pub="http://comppress.com/publications">
    <pub:name>Everwhere Media</pub:name>
    <pub:id>GF0755</pub:id>
    <pub:number></pub:number>
    <pub:countPrinted>172</pub:countPrinted>
    <pub:distributorsSent></pub:distributorsSent>
    <pub:description></pub:description>
    <pub:creationDate></pub:creationDate>
    <pub:lastPrinted>Jan 17, 2016</pub:lastPrinted>
    <pub:purpose></pub:purpose>
</pub:publication>

</compPress>
```

XSD:

```
<xs:schema 
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="urn:schema"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="compPress">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="dist:distributor">
                    <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="dist:name" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="dist:id" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="dist:description" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="dist:contractDate" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="dist:address" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="dist:contactName" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="dist:serviceRegion" type="xs:string" />
                            </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="xmlns:dist" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="div:division">
                    <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="div:name" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="div:number" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="div:description" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="div:numberEmployees" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="div:creationDate" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="div:mission" type="xs:string" />
                            </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="xmlns:div" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="pub:publication">
                    <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="pub:name" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="pub:id" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="pub:number" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="pub:countPrinted" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="pub:distributorsSent" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="pub:description" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="pub:creationDate" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="pub:lastPrinted" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="pub:purpose" type="xs:string" />
                            </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="xmlns:pub" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and any help is greatly appreciated.